# The controller with the name 'PokemonCtrl' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

I am trying to add a controller to my Angularjs app.

This is the first time I have set it up without using `$scope` as a dependency and used the routes to declare what controller I am using.

What am I doing wrong where `PokemonCtrl` is not registered? Also, if I declare the controller in the routing does that mean I don't have to declare it anywhere else?

**app.js**

```
    'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name pokedexApp
 * @description
 * # pokedexApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
    .module('pokedexApp', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch'
    ])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'main'
            })
            .when('/pokemon', {
                templateUrl: 'views/pokemon.html',
                controller: 'PokemonCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'controller'

            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/main'
            });
    });
```

**pokemonCtrl.js**

```
    'use strict';

var pokedexApp = angular.module('pokedexApp', []);

pokedexApp.controller('PokemonCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.text = "Catch em All!"

});
```

Comment: Add your controller 'pokemonCtrl.js' to index page :)

Comment: This fixed it!! I keep forgetting that you need to call each controller in the index page! I am used to .Net MVC where you can bundle and no longer worry about it! Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is you are overriding your module definition. When you write this line :

```
var pokedexApp = angular.module('pokedexApp', []);
```

you are defining a module. If you call it again, with the same name and passing an empty array, you override it. If you just want to retrieve your module, you go with

```
var pokedexApp = angular.module('pokedexApp');
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your pokemonCtrl.js you need to remove the `[]` from the `angular.module` statement.

What is actually happening here is you are generating a new module instead of referencing your one from app.js

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you are creating an angular app in `app.js` but are not assigning it to any global-scoped var that you can then *add on* to later, like when defining a new controller. You do that later in `pokemonCtrl.js` but then all the Angular Dependencies -- `ngAnimate` and `ngCookies` -- will not be available, nor will your config with routes be setup.

You'll need to set it up like so:

**app.js**

```
// Define your global angular app var
var pokedexApp = angular
.module('pokedexApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
]);

pokedexApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'main'
        })
        .when('/pokemon', {
            templateUrl: 'views/pokemon.html',
            controller: 'PokemonCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'controller'

        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/main'
        });
});
```

**pokemonCtrl.js**

```
// Adding a note here, I am setting up this controller 
// by enclosing the function within an Array, you don't *have* to
// do this, but it helps in the future if this file gets minified
// by letting Angular *know* what the mapping is for this controller's
// dependencies.

pokedexApp.controller('PokemonCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  // you need to let this controller know you want to have access
  // to the "scope" -- $scope
  $scope.text = "Catch em All!";
}]);
```

**HTML File**

```
<h1>{{text}}</h1>
```

Comment: How can I do this without using $scope? I have read on Jon Pappa's Angular Stylesheet that it's better to not use $scope so it doesn't cause collisions with parent scope and child scope.

Comment: You have to use `$scope` to let the page or element that is binded to the controller to have access to that information.

Comment: I recommend to give a read through of the Angular documentation. `$scope` plays a big part in Angular Apps and knowing what it is and how to use it is vital for a nice app. Additionally, the "parent" scope, or your root controller (you can have multiple controllers going on) would be accessed by `$parent` anyways.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope